# Get user name & mail id from Sharepoint Popularity Trends

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Is there any way to find the name and email-ID of unique users for sharepoint library from powershell. I found the count from "Popularity Trend" excel,but i want the users details.

I am sharepoint admin and have complete access on farm so powershell will also work for me.

Thanks in Advance for your guidance.